# How to extract a project tree from a git archive

Tags: git

I'm new to git and trying to do what I thought would be trivial.  I just want to extract the files from the downloaded archive.

I used `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git`

I got a directory "common" with several subdirs including `common/.git/objects/pack/*biglongname*.pack` and a similarly named .idx file.

I've search all over for a simple command to extract the source files.  I've tried *git archive*, *git unpack-objects*, *git pull* and a bunch of others with no joy.

What am I missing here?  this just *has* to be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository is a bit strange, since the `HEAD` has no files in it. You have to checkout one of the two real branches:

```
 git checkout android-3.0
```

or

```
 git checkout android-2.6.39
```

Comment: this worked perfectly.  Thanks mucho.  And thanks to other responders too!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the source, not the repository, just delete the entire `.git` subdirectory.

If you've cloned the repository and you have nothing but the `.git` folder, try creating a branch to checkout the code:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

do this within the `common` directory.

I'm surprised that [`git archive`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-archive.html) didn't work for you. That is another way of extracting the source to a different place.

Comment: Hmmm. All I got was the .git and subdirectories. If I delete that, nothin's left.

Comment: I tried "*git achive something* > mytar but I couldn't figure out what *something* should be.

Comment: Try checking out the source as I've edited my answer to describe.

Answer (score 1):

The development in this particular repository doesn't happen on the `master` branch (the default branch checked out after the clone). You can use `gitk` to visualize what happened in any branch, e.g. for the last year

```
$ gitk --all --since='last year'
```

There you will see lots of commits to e.g. the `android-3.0` branch. To switch your clone to that branch do

```
$ git checkout android-3.0
```

Had you known this you could have specified the branch to checkout after the clone at clone time

```
$ git clone -b android-3.0 https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
```